# Swift pick random item of Set<T>

Tags: swift, set

I know, a `Set` is an unordered datastructure, however I wondered if it is possible to pick a random object of the Set's entries. Is this possible in Swift and in case of yes, how? Could I use Swift 1.2 `Set<T>` or would I have to use `NSMutableSet` or even `NSOrderedSet`?

Comment: Swift 4.2: `let random = mySet.randomElement()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets don’t have random-access iterators, but if you are willing to pay the price of linear-time advance over the length of the set, you could do this:

```
import Darwin
let set = Set("supercalifragalisticexpialidocious")
let offset = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(set.count)))
let idx = advance(set.startIndex, offset)

set[idx] // a random entry from set
```